# Efficient method to exclude items in one list from another list in Python

Tags: python, string, list, tokenize, stop-words

I have a list of 8000 strings (stop_words) and a list of 100,000 strings of various lengths running to millions of individual words. I am using the function to tokenize the 100,000 string and to exclude non alphanumeric tokens and tokens from the list stop_words.

```
    def tokenizer(text):

       return [stemmer.stem(tok.lower()) for tok in nltk.word_tokenize(text)/ 
       if tok.isalpha() and tok.lower() not in stop_words]
```

I have tested this code using 600 strings and it takes 60 seconds. If I remove the condition to exclude stopwords it takes 1 second on the same 600 strings

```
    def tokenizer(text):

       return [stemmer.stem(tok.lower()) for tok in nltk.word_tokenize(text)/ 
       if tok.isalpha()]
```

I am hoping there is a more efficient way to exclude items found in one list from another list.

I am grateful for any help or suggestions

Thanks

Comment: Try `set` to exclude similar items. `set(list1).difference(list2)` [see](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Make `stop_words` a set, since [checking membership in a set](http://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity) is O(1),
  while checking membership in a list is O(N).
- Call `lower()` on `text` (once) instead of `lower()` twice for each
  token.

---

```
stop_words = set(stop_words)
def tokenizer(text):
   return [stemmer.stem(tok) for tok in nltk.word_tokenize(text.lower())
           if tok.isalpha() and tok not in stop_words]
```

---

Since accessing local variables is quicker than looking up qualified names, you may also gain a bit of speed by making `nltk.word_tokenize` and `stemmer.stem` local:

```
stop_words = set(stop_words)
def tokenizer(text, stem = stemmer.stem, tokenize = nltk.word_tokenize):
   return [stem(tok) for tok in tokenize(text.lower())
           if tok.isalpha() and tok not in stop_words]
```

The default values for `stem` and `tokenize` are set *once* at the time the `tokenizer` function is *defined*. Inside `tokenizer`, `stem` and `tokenize` are local variables. Usually this kind of micro-optimization is not important, but since you are calling `tokenizer`
100K times, it may help you a little bit.

Answer (score 5):

Make `stop_words` a set so that lookups are O(1) instead.

```
stop_words = set(('word1', 'word2', 'word3'))
```

Comment: Thanks- this is a great deal quicker

Answer (score 0):

Use sets:

```
{x for x in one_list} - other_list
```

However it removes duplicates and ordering, so if it matters you need something else.

Comment: Thanks, although in this instance I do need to keep dups